# Is there way to code export tests from multiple .side files as a batch?

Tags: java, junit, selenium-ide

I have tests within multiple .side extension files. Is there a way to export tests or suite of tests from all the .side files to WebDriver code without manually having to select Export for each project within IDE?

The selenium command line runner is able to run multiple .side files as a batch but does not have a code export option.

As mentioned in the [docs](https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/command-line-runner):

```
selenium-side-runner --output-directory=results --output-format=junit
# Outputs results in `junit` frormat in `./results/projectName.xml'
```

The command will output the test execution report in XML format. But not the Java JUnit code for every test.